# JavaScript not executing completely on home button press in iOS Cordova app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, websocket, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a Cordova based iphone app.
For a particular requirement, I want to close websocket connection with my server when the home button is pressed. In the current scenario, when I press the home button, the JavaScript unloads before the function that closes the websocket runs completely. And it completes when the app is started again(using VOIP notification). Due to which I am facing some bugs in the app. I have to close the websocket before the js unloads. Is there a way I can do this in Cordova based iOS apps.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [Cordova Background Mode Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) to your project then `Enable background-mode` on `deviceready`

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

When your `websocket` close then after again call function of `Disable Background mode` like

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disable();
```

This will make working your javascript code when you press home button and it completes your requirement then after it will automatically disable background-mode so your app will not get memory loads.

Comment: Hi @Kirankumar, I checked the link you shared in your answer. It says under the store compliance section "**The plugin focuses on enterprise-only distribution and may not compliant with all public store vendors**".Does this mean app store will reject it? I need to upload this app on app store.

Comment: No, app store will not reject this but you have to set specific reason into `info.plist` file `UIBackgroundModes key` and app store will check the dependency, I have used this plugin into mine applications too. And its successfully uploaded into app store. So you can use this without any problem.